# How to add more than one UIBarButtonItem to rightBarButtonItem in ios7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, xcode5, rightbarbuttonitem

I have an existing code which was working fine in ios6. but in ios7 left most item("refresh button") is not showing align to other two UIBarButtonItem . its showing little down. here is the code for iOS6. what changes do i need to make this working in iOS7.

```
 // create an array for the buttons
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

// create a standard save button
UIBarButtonItem* refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                  target:self
                                  action:@selector(refreshButtonClicked:)];

refreshButton.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshButton;

[buttons addObject:refreshButton];
[refreshButton release];

// create a spacer between the buttons
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                           target:nil
                           action:nil];

[buttons addObject:spacer];
[spacer release];

// create a standard delete button with the trash icon
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(InfoButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[buttons addObject:infoItem];

// put the buttons in the toolbar and release them
[toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
[buttons release];

// place the toolbar into the navigation bar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithCustomView:toolbar]autorelease];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;`

Comment: Thanks Leo. following line of code resolved the issue for me. 

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:refreshButton, infoItem,nil];